# jQuery match data-attribute value of object within array of attributes

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to find an object in an array of data objects by matching the value of one of the attributes in the objects.  My title may not be the best, but I'm not exactly sure how to describe this.

For example, for the following div, I want to get the entire list of "attributes" for the color "black" from the "data-variants" array:
(I have expanded the html for easier reading)

```
<div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1463518293327_182" class="product-variants" data-variants="
[
    {"attributes":
        {"color":"red"},
        "optionValues":[{"optionName":"color","value":"red"}],
        "sku":"SQ7490795",
        "price":2000,
        "salePrice":0,
        "onSale":false,
        "unlimited":false,
        "qtyInStock":1,
        "len":0.0,
        "width":0.0,
        "height":0.0,
        "weight":0.0
    },

{"attributes":{"color":"black"},"optionValues":[{"optionName":"color","value":"black"}],"sku":"SQ0598849","price":2000,"salePrice":0,"onSale":false,"unlimited":false,"qtyInStock":1,"len":0.0,"width":0.0,"height":0.0,"weight":0.0},

{"attributes":{"color":"orange"},"optionValues":[{"optionName":"color","value":"orange"}],"sku":"SQ5650843","price":2000,"salePrice":0,"onSale":false,"unlimited":false,"qtyInStock":1,"len":0.0,"width":0.0,"height":0.0,"weight":0.0}

]" 

data-item-id="570c23edf699bb9c6946e2e7">
```

I have tried various versions of this:

```
console.log( $('.product-variants').data("variants").attributes("color" = "black") );
```

but I either get errors or undefined.

By the way, the HTML data is generated dynamically by the platform (Squarespace), so I don't have access to change it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try using single quotes instead of double quotes for your data-variants attribute? The double quotes are closing when the first double quotes start at "attributes". So try this  data-variants='
[
    {"attributes":  (.....) ' <-closing single quote.

Comment: Thanks, but the data is generated dynamically by the platform (Squarespace), so I don't have access to change the formatting.  I'll add this to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML you are showing is being generated directly by Squarespace then you're not going to be able to use it because the markup is invalid. Can you provide a the exact code being used to load the data from Squarespace?

If you define the `data-variants` property using double quotes then you can't use double quotes inside the property. The following example works perfectly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var data = $('.product-variants').data("variants");
            $.each(data, function() {
                console.log(this["sku"]);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1463518293327_182" class="product-variants" data-variants='[
    {"attributes": {"color":"red"},"optionValues":[{"optionName":"color","value":"red"}],"sku":"SQ7490795","price":2000,"salePrice":0,"onSale":false,"unlimited":false,"qtyInStock":1,"len":0.0,"width":0.0,"height":0.0,"weight":0.0 },
    {"attributes":{"color":"black"},"optionValues":[{"optionName":"color","value":"black"}],"sku":"SQ0598849","price":2000,"salePrice":0,"onSale":false,"unlimited":false,"qtyInStock":1,"len":0.0,"width":0.0,"height":0.0,"weight":0.0},
    {"attributes":{"color":"orange"},"optionValues":[{"optionName":"color","value":"orange"}],"sku":"SQ5650843","price":2000,"salePrice":0,"onSale":false,"unlimited":false,"qtyInStock":1,"len":0.0,"width":0.0,"height":0.0,"weight":0.0}
]' data-item-id="570c23edf699bb9c6946e2e7"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually I tried your example function and it works for me as well, even with the invalid markup.  Why, I don't know.  But this is helpful, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change the double quotes to single quotes in element attribute in order to escape the double quotes in the JSON inside the attribute value.

Then you will have to make a loop trought the attribute object to check whatever you want.

```
// Get the attribute value (jQuery already parses it as Object)
    var json = $(".product-variants").data("variants");

    // Make a loop trhougt the JSON object and check if it's color property is 'black'
    $.each(json, function () {
        if (this.attributes.color == "black") {
            // If it's 'black' then print it in the "#result" element
            $("#result").text( JSON.stringify(this) ); // 'this' is your result
        }
    });
```

Take a look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/evandroprogram/nf5zq63z/